# How can I programatically remove options that follow a given pattern from an html select form?

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu

I have this very inneficient function which gets the options from a select dropdown inside an html form and removes three of the options. Considering that I may have dozens of options, I would like to remove all of them that begin with "2.", regardless of what comes after that. How can I achieve that?

```
function removeOptions() {
  var selectForm = document.getElementById("form");
  var options = selectForm.options;
  for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
    if(options[i].text==='2.1 4AA') selectForm.remove(i);
    if(options[i].text==='2.2 A23') selectForm.remove(i);
    if(options[i].text==='2.3 BBB') selectForm.remove(i);
    if(options[i].text==='2.4 AAA') selectForm.remove(i);
}
}
```